# Creating object in front of player, with some distance

Tags: transformation, godot

I want to create objects in front of player with some distance, so that prevents hit with player immediately. So first, I get the global player position and direction vector which player towards:

```
var player_position = player.transform.origin
var player_forward_vector = player.global_transform.basis.z
```

And then give additional distance:

```
var spawn_position = player_position
spawn_position.z -= player_forward_vector.z + 100
```

And then set the position:

```
var asteroid_instance = asteroid_scene.instance()
asteroid_instance.transform.origin = spawn_position
```

When I run the game, first it seems work, however when I rotated the player, still object spawned same position, not in front of where I'm looking at.

Here's the video to demonstrate:
https://youtu.be/zvMU9ad33SA

Why object doesn't created in front of player, instead keep spawns in same location? Any advice will very appreciate it.

Here's the full code of spawning object. Note that asteroid is just Rigidbody object with collision shape as child.

```
# AsteroidSpawner.gd
extends Node

onready var player: Player = get_tree().get_root().find_node("Player", true, false)
var asteroid_scene: PackedScene = preload("res://Asteroid/Asteroid.tscn")

func _ready():
    spawn_asteroids()

func spawn_asteroids():
    while true:
        spawn_asteroid()
        yield(get_tree().create_timer(2), "timeout")

func spawn_asteroid():
    var spawn_position: Vector3 = get_spawn_position()

    var asteroid_instance = asteroid_scene.instance()
    asteroid_instance.global_transform.origin = spawn_position

    # Push towards player
    var direction_to_player: Vector3 = player.transform.origin - spawn_position
    var speed = min(rand_range(5, 10), 10)
    asteroid_instance.add_force(direction_to_player * speed, Vector3())

    add_child(asteroid_instance)

func get_spawn_position() -> Vector3:
    var player_position = player.global_transform.origin
    var player_forward_vector = player.global_transform.basis.z
    var spawn_position = player_position
    spawn_position.z -= player_forward_vector.z + 100

    return spawn_position
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information to say for sure, but you're mixing local and global transforms. If you're basing the spawned object location on the players *global* transform, you should set `asteroid.global_tranform.origin`. Otherwise the resulting position will be affected by the parent's transform.

Comment: Thanks, but change to using global_transform doesn't do anything. Which information wasn't enough to you? That's the all do spawning object in my actual game.

Comment: That can't be all the spawning logic, as there's no call to `add_child`. Try formulating a [minimal, complete, and reproduceable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Added code I used, include add_child. I rid off all unnecessary parts, and confirmed that it reproduced the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define the `offset` between player and spawn location as a `Vector3`.
2. Get the rotation of the player as a quaternion, using `var rotation = player.global_transform.basis.get_rotation_quat( )`
3. Rotate the spawn offset vector by that quaternion, using the xform method. Like this: `var rotated_offset = rotation.xform( offset )`
4. Add the player position and the rotated offset together: `var spawn_point = player.global_transform.origin + rotated_offset`

By the way, you can skip the quaternion and just do `var rotated_offset = player.global_transform.basis.xform( offset )`. But then the scale factor of the player will affect the distance of the spawn point.